# Workaround for settings apps URL schemes for devices using ios 5.1

Tags: ios, url, schema, preferences, ios5.1

Does anyone know a workaround for settings apps URL schemes for devices using ios 5.1?

For example :

> [UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URWithString:@"prefs:root=NOTIFICATIONS_ID"]];

Thanks